# How to put information from one Ajax request into another

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have this code to get two parts of data, these two ajax requests get data from php class.

```
                       {
                       xtype: 'button',
                       formBind: true,
                       id: 'saveLicenceBtn',
                       text: 'Save',
                       listeners: {
                           click: function (c) {
                               //first ajax request
                               var d = Ext.Ajax.request({
                                   url: 'system/index.php',
                                   params: {
                                       class: 'generatemultiple',
                                       method: 'getSession'
                                   },
                                   success: function (response) {
                                       var object = Ext.decode(response.responseText, true);
                                       console.log(object);
                                   },
                                   failure: function (response) {
                                       var object = Ext.decode(response.responseText, true);
                                       console.log(object);
                                   }
                               });
                               //second ajax request
                               Ext.Ajax.request({
                                   url: 'system/index.php',
                                   method: 'POST',
                                   params: {
                                       class: 'generatemultiple',
                                       method: 'add',
                                       data: Ext.encode({
                                           count: Ext.getCmp('count').getValue(),
                                           start_date: Ext.getCmp('startdateTextField').getValue(),
                                           end_date: Ext.getCmp('enddateTextField').getValue(),
                                           duration: Ext.getCmp('durationTextField').getValue(),
                                           expiry_date: Ext.getCmp('expirydateTextField').getValue(),
                                           product_id: Ext.getCmp('productidTextField').getValue(),
                                           company_id: Ext.getCmp('companyidtf').getValue(),
                                           token: d
                                       })
                                   },
                                   success: function (response) {
                                       Ext.MessageBox.alert('Status', 'Success');
                                       Ext.getStore('LicenseStore').reload();
                                       Ext.getStore('LicenseAllStore').reload();
                                       Ext.getStore('LicenseFeaturesStore').reload();
                                       Ext.getStore('HardwareStore').reload();
                                       Ext.getStore('DropdownLicenseStore').reload();
                                       Ext.getStore('GridHardwareStore').reload();
                                       Ext.getStore('HardwareAllStore').reload();
                                       Ext.getCmp('addLicenseWindow').close();
                                   },
                                   failure: function (response) {
                                       Ext.MessageBox.alert('Status', 'Failure');
                                       Ext.getCmp('addLicenseWindow').close();
                                   }
                               });
                           }
                       }
                   }
```

The first ajax request gets a session variable from the webpage, and the second ajax request sends this token with the ajax request. What I need to know is how do I do what is shown here without getting this error.

`Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

I know what the error means and I am aware of the reason why its occuring, but i cant find a solution. it keeps occuring because I have two functions calling each other so it errors in the web console.

What i tried alternatively was this

ONCLICK

```
    click: function (c) {
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: 'system/index.php',
        method: 'POST',
        params: {
            class: 'generatemultiple',
            method: 'add',
            data: Ext.encode({
                count: Ext.getCmp('count').getValue(),
                start_date: Ext.getCmp('startdateTextField').getValue(),
                end_date: Ext.getCmp('enddateTextField').getValue(),
                duration: Ext.getCmp('durationTextField').getValue(),
                expiry_date: Ext.getCmp('expirydateTextField').getValue(),
                product_id: Ext.getCmp('productidTextField').getValue(),
                company_id: Ext.getCmp('companyidtf').getValue(),
                token: '<?php echo $_SESSION["user_id"] ?>'
            })
        },
        success: function (response) {
            Ext.MessageBox.alert('Status', 'Success');
            Ext.getStore('LicenseStore').reload();
            Ext.getStore('LicenseAllStore').reload();
            Ext.getStore('LicenseFeaturesStore').reload();
            Ext.getStore('HardwareStore').reload();
            Ext.getStore('DropdownLicenseStore').reload();
            Ext.getStore('GridHardwareStore').reload();
            Ext.getStore('HardwareAllStore').reload();
            Ext.getCmp('addLicenseWindow').close();
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            Ext.MessageBox.alert('Status', 'Failure');
            Ext.getCmp('addLicenseWindow').close();
        }
    });
}
```

forgive the indentation. End goal of what I am trying to do is send the session variable from the php with this ajax request

Comment: You can just nest the second request into the `success` function of the first.

Comment: I did that still gave me the error indicated above

Comment: please don't paste the whole code in the question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You can make first ajax request as a synchronous call So that second ajax request will wait for the first ajax request to complete. Set "async: false" in the first request.

Comment: What I really need to understand is why does token: '<?php echo $_SESSION["user_id"] ?>' work

Comment: oh I see, sorry but how could I do that

Answer (score 0):

You can make first ajax request as a synchronous call So that second ajax request will wait for the first ajax request to complete. Set `async: false` in the first request.

Comment: Mmh tried that still same error as before, I am beggining to think it might be something else